# Wrapper for default date constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like a kind of wrapper for the default `Date` object in JavaScript so that whenever I have something like `var a = new Date();`, I want to execute some particular code in the constructor.

I basically want to have my own Date class that needs to be invoked whenever a call is made to `Date()` rather than the native code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the reference for the native `Date` object, than make your own wrapper, which invokes the native `Date` then mutates it, or adds additional behavior.

```
var OldDate = Date;
var Date = function() {
  var that = new OldDate();
  that.mystuff = 5;
  // do other things with the date
  // and execute your own things
  // ...
  return that;
}

var now = new Date();
alert(now.mystuff);
```

However, I wouldn't mess with native objects.